# Se cierra la agenda despues de encontrar un contacto

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo el siguiente proyecto:

[image: Menu]

El Programa si Guarda y Muestra todos los contactos guardados.

Pero cuando busca 1 contaco y lo encuentra el programa se cierra, esto sucede cuando hay mas de 1 contacto guardado

Este es el codigo de la funcion buscar:

```
void consulta(vector<Agenda> contactos)
{
Agenda a;
int i=0, band;
char rep;

system("cls");
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t ***BUSCAR CONTACTO***";
cout<<"\n\tIngresa el Nombre a buscar: ";
cin>>a.buscador;
band=0;
while(i<=contactos.size())
{
    if(contactos[i].nombre == a.buscador)
    {
        cout<<"\n\t\tNombre: "<<contactos[i].nombre;
        cout<<"\n\t\tDireccion: "<<contactos[i].direccion;
        cout<<"\n\t\tTelefono: "<<contactos[i].telefono;
        cout<<"\n\t\tEmail: "<<contactos[i].email<<"\n";
        band=1;
    }
    i++;                        
}
if(band==0)
    cout<<"\n\t\tContacto no registrado\n";
}
```

La estructura de la agenda es la siguiente:

```
struct Agenda{

string nombre;
string direccion;
string telefono;
string email;
string buscador;
int size;
};
```

La funcion la mando a llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
 case 4:
            system("cls");
            if(a.size>0)
            {
                do{
                    consulta(contactos);
                    cout<<"\n\n\t\tBuscar otro contacto s/n?: ";
                    cin>>rep;
                }while(rep != 'n');
            }
            else
              cout<<"\n\t\t***AGENDA VACIA***\n";
            system("pause");
            break;
```

Espero me puedan ayudar...

Comment: Por favor, no pegues el código **como imágenes**. Impides que otros puedan copiar/pegar para ayudarte. Coloca siempre el código **como texto**.

Comment: `while(i<=contactos.size())` está mal, debería ser `while(i<contactos.size())`.

Comment: Voto por cerrarla como `Error tipográfico`.

Comment: @Trauma Muchas gracias por tu comentarios. Deja modificar la pregunta.

Comment: hay un `char rep` que declaras en la función `consulta` que creo que no sirve, bueno, fuera de eso, he intentado reproducir lo que has hecho y todo funciona, parece que el problema está en otro lado.